# Suitable format for language specific code golfing tips

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm not a huge fan of seeing ['Tips for Golfing in language'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) in the Code golf questions page - and I wonder if there could be a more suitable format for this type of question.

Perhaps something like Stackoverflow's tag wiki's. Where each people could contribute to a knowledge base of each language's code golfing nuances.

Is there any interest in this idea / would it be achievable?

Answer (score 2):

Tag wikis are not editable by low-rep users. Also they don't allow people to contribute individual tips. :-(

Comment: While asking this question I noticed [this link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to the StackExchange blog post about (essentially) this. I just think there should be a better way to share code golfing tips, than by asking and answering a question.

Comment: Would it make sense to migrate the tips questions to meta?

Answer (score 1):

They're not usually a nuisance on the questions page - there's rarely more than two. And to be honest, I think that the "traditional" format of a question and then one tip per answer is a lot more readable than your "bundle all the tips into the question" layout.